# VSTO Word 2007/2010 Addin: positioning items in File menu

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-addins

I have a VSTO Word addin created for Word 2007, using .NET 4.0. The addin works perfectly with both Word 2007 and 2010 versions.
My problem is as you can see on the picture, that menu items are positioned correctly in 2007, but not in 2010.
[image]

The ribbon was created by the GUI designer, so it is not XML based.

Is it possible to position the menu items correctly in Word 2010 using the GUI designer or it is possible only if the ribbon is XML based?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a better compatibility MS suggests to use XML based Ribbon.

When you create a Word 2010 Ribbon using VS2010 or VS2012 by Visual Designer (VS2010 or VS2012) then the position is skipped on backstage (file menu).

This is a bug in 2010.

Comment: Unfortunately the Ribbon Designer is not a terribly useful tool in most cases. The Ribbon XML works far better.